# Jenkins 2.7.x Role Strategy Plugin

Tags: jenkins, authorization

Using Jenkins 2.7.x I am trying to configure the [Role based Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin), but facing some issue.

Scenario is, there are 2 teams products I & P each can have Dev, Admin & Lead.

So created 6 LDAP (project) roles & one CI_Admin global role.

[image]

and assigned these roles to LDAP user group

[image]

Now when the admin logs in he gets error

[image]

What am i missing ?

Comment: I've experienced something/somehow similiar because of nested Active Directory (AD) groups. During research I found [JENKINS-37858](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37858). Maybe this is also releated to it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in global roles in (Fig 3 Highlighted in the below image) read permission is missing. so to login to Jenkins user/group should have read permission.

[image]